# How to append data to pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a list of string elements with different lengths.

I would like to add to a dataframe each numerical values for each element of the list. The final result should looks like this:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd


lst = ['86:99', '105:76 OT (87:87)']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in lst:
    df = df.append(
    {
    'f1' : re.findall('[0-9]+', x).[0],
    'f2' : re.findall('[0-9]+', x).[1],
    'f3' : re.findall('[0-9]+', x).[2],
    'f4' : re.findall('[0-9]+', x).[3]
    },
    ignore_index = True)
```

I have a error result:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Maybe you can help. Thanks

Comment: Couple things. (1) your code does not run as is, (2) what is `a`?

Comment: sorry not a[x] but lst[x]

Comment: swapping `lst` for `a` still doesn't make this runnable

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
import re
x='86:99'
re.findall('[0-9]+', x) # output -- > ['86', '99']
re.findall('[0-9]+', x)[0] # '86'
re.findall('[0-9]+', x)[1] # 99''
re.findall('[0-9]+', x)[2] # IndexError: list index out of range. Because we have only two values.
```

You can use an if else block to prevent this.

```
lst = ['86:99', '105:76 OT (87:87)']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in lst:
    df = df.append({'f1' : re.findall('[0-9]+', x)[0],
    'f2' : re.findall('[0-9]+', x)[1],
    'f3' : re.findall('[0-9]+', x)[2] if len(re.findall('[0-9]+', x)) > 2 else np.nan,
     'f4' : re.findall('[0-9]+', x)[3] if len(re.findall('[0-9]+', x)) > 3 else np.nan
     },
    ignore_index = True)

'''
    f1  f2  f3  f4
0   86  99  nan nan 
1   105 76  87  87

'''
```